# SearchQuery by Not in Uids MailKit

Tags: c#, mailkit, mimekit

I want to read the emails on the basis of Uids which are not recorded in my database. How can I give the SearchQuery to find only those Uids which are not saved in my database. In bellow code, I do not want to read 6504 uid because it is present in my database.

```
var range = new UniqueIdRange(new UniqueId((uint)6504), UniqueId.MaxValue);
foreach (var uid in inbox.Search(!range, SearchQuery.All))
{
    var message = inbox.GetMessage(uid);
}
```

Any help please?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use the SearchQuery.Not() expression:

```
var knownUids = new UniqueIdSet ();

knownUids.Add (new UniqueId ((uint) 6504));

foreach (var uid in inbox.Search (SearchQuery.Not (SearchQuery.Uids (knownUids))) {
    var message = inbox.GetMessage (uid);
}
```

Comment: Great! it works. But what if there is no Uids present in DB ie on first time? It gives error.

Comment: if you have no uids, then just do a full search using inbox.Search (SearchQuery.All);